# Sqoop to SQL Server. Blank string error

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to load data from sqoop to sql server. I'm writing:

> ```
> sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<server name>;username=<user>;
> password=<pass>;database=<db>" --table test_out --input-fields-terminated-by ~
>  --export-dir /user/test.out
> ```

but I get error when row has blank string in test.out:

```
1~a
<nul>~b
<blank>~c
```

In this example, the third line returns an error:

```
 Failed map tasks=1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look into the Failed map task log as it usually contains quite detail information about the failure.

Sqoop will always expect that the number of columns on every line in the exported data will be equal to the number of columns in target table. While exporting from text file, the number of columns will be determined by the number of separators present on the line. Based on provided example it seems that the target table have 2 columns, whereas the third line have zero separators and thus it's assume that it's one single column. This discrepancy would cause Sqoop to fail.

Comment: I'm sorry, third row has delimeter. How I can view  detail information about the failure?

In log:

Comment: INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
2013-11-22 16:05:08,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=16
2013-11-22 16:05:08,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=16
2013-11-22 16:05:08,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
2013-11-22 16:05:08,219 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1